# Speech Recognition - Linear predictive coding

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, fft, speech

I am working / researching a project idea for educational purposes and want to do the project about speech recognition, nothing too big just an introduction to get my started in the field. Basically, the project and algorithm will take an input of a (.wav) file and then identify if the person speaking is either saying "Yes" or saying "No". I'm looking to use Linear Predictive Coding.

Basically, in my head, I'm thinking of the following Algorithm:

1. Read in the .wav (raw data) into a vector
2. Split the vector into equal size blocks
3. Process each block for particular characteristics
4. Find the word whose model is the most likely match to the string of phones which was produced.

Then I would like to use similarity measures such as Correlation to find the correct Phone(s).

So, basically, after the data file has been read in, and, split into blocks.. It should/would contain like this:

```
rawdata = 

[0] => 'Y',
[1] => 'E',
[2] => 'S'
```

Or will contain the frequency result which can then be compared with the Phones.

My question is, does this look like a good algorithm to work off to solve the problem..

My next question:

When I try to read in a .wav file into memory, I get (Kind of) the following results..

```
20 30 10 30 40 50 .. 20 20 .. 10 20 .. 60 40 
10 20 30 40 50 60 ... .. . . . .
```

They are all integer values, so, once I have taken all the header information.. The rest of the data is what I need to convert into the correct medium and then this is the data..? I'm kinda confused.

Hope someone can help me, and, I've written the problem out correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Why did I get negative feedback?!? How was that unclear?? God

Comment: Because your question is overly broad.

Comment: I don't know what is your C++ level, and if you're a master than please ignore this comment, but in my experience sort out an algorithm in Matlab and then move to C++. Signal and Image processing is much easier and shorter in Matlab than in C++.

Comment: You are sort of asking for the contents of many random chapters of textbooks on speech recognition and audio DSP.  So go read a few books on the subject first.

Comment: Heyy thanks for your replies.. I got the algorithm, and, idea from this guy: cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/speech.html his implementation of the problem is good. I want to do something simular to this, however, changing it to LPC.

Comment: What makes you think that LPC is a good idea ?

Comment: I believe your question belongs to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't my opinion, no it's not a good algorithm.

First of all people speak with different speed, and they pronounce characters with different speed too. You can't start off with slicing your input data randomly.

Second, to get some good results, you need to reduce the noise of the input drastically. You need to concentrate to the frequencies human speech uses mostly. Then you need something to identify the vowels first, and then you try to guess the word, and you need some real data for that. You probably won't get any usable though.

to answer your question about the waw file, thats header + data, I don't know about the header, but since waw is an ancient format, it won't be that hard to get some docs on it.

The data part is an array of integer values, that the intensity of the sound in a given moment. The intensity was measured 44 000 times per second for a 44 kHz waw file, and stored. it's just the raw numbers, no compression at all (ever wondered why waw file are so huge?) except for the header, which tells you the sampling rate and the integer type (usually 16 bit), among other things.

You analyze this huge data to obtain some info about the frequencies used, but you should really research the mathematics of sounds and everything, before you even start. Heck, even I'm not sure I could write something, that successfully recognizes 3 letter words about half the time.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply.. I found out about splitting the sample into equal parts from here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~dwagn/aiproj/speech.html his algorith / implementation seems to work.. I just want to do it differently and use Linear Predictive Coding over zerocrossing..